# Creating a Font w/o New Software

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, fonts

I recently asked [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40866/creating-a-font-file-in-photoshop-and-or-illustrator) and I left out a few things. As I mentioned in that question, I have psd files for each letter as well as svg files for each letter. I do not want to use some other software for building the font. I want to go about a more hands on approach. How can this be done, if, it can be done?
Basically, I'm asking how font builder software outputs the font files as I want to skip the software.

Comment: Please [edit] your original question instead of creating a duplicate. I flagged this for conversion into your other Q. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: @Vincent in the duplicate question message it says to either edit your question, or ask a new one. I have decided to create a new one.

Comment: *scratches back of head* As Scott said in your original question, I think it's rather impossible without resorting to hard-coding things yourself. If that's your intention, your Q is still off-topic and should go to a programmer SE, imho.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions on the same topic.  I would encourage you to make an edit to your original question if you feel it shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be done? Sure, I did [exactly this](http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2012/06/indyfont-build-opentype-fonts-from-within-indesign) in Javascript, where InDesign is only used to draw curves with. The rest is done entirely with Javascript.

All "font builder software" does is gather all the necessary information, format it according to the specification(s), and then write it out a file.

Read *everything* you can find on the specifications for the font type you want to create; [Microsoft's](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/default.htm), for instance, for OpenType/TTF flavor.
You also need to know how to convert your current images to the specific *vector format* for your font type of choice, for instance, TrueType instructions for a TTF or PostScript for a Type-1 OTF.

How? Basically, that question is way too broad for *any* forum I am aware of.